# Cambiar orden de etiqueta

Tags: r

Tengo estos datos para hacer un gráfico

```
  structure(list(long = c(-5.77429577, -6.1744383, -5.51043948, 
    -4.78653821, -5.27186009, -5.03263327, -5.70787858, -4.92538225, 
    -5.82575198), lat = c(37.31276016, 37.46251315, 37.58414736, 
    37.33243854, 37.25666274, 37.32504325, 38.18830018, 37.19940005, 
    37.0719157), group = c("34014141004.1", "34014141003.1", "34014141024.1", 
    "34014141041.1", "34014141060.1", "34014141084.1", "34014141048.1", 
    "34014141046.1", "34014141904.1"), nombre_municipio = c("Mun4", 
    "Mun5", "Mun2", "Mun3", "Mun1", "Mun6", "Mun7", "Mun9", "Mun8"
    ), Tipo = c("Muy baja", "Muy baja", "Baja", "Baja", "Media", 
    "Media", "Alta", "Alta", "Desconocido"), Valor = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame")) -> datos
```

Hago el gráfico

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

datos %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = Tipo)) +
  geom_polygon(color = "black") +
  coord_map("mercator")
```

(No importa que no salga bien, he reducido datos)

Quiero cambiar el orden de la leyenda a "Muy baja, Baja, Media, Alta, Desconocido"

y aquí fallo.

```
datos[order(datos$Valor),] -> datos

datos$Tipo <- factor(datos$Tipo,  levels = datos$Valor)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás bien rumbeado, la idea es convertir a la columna Tipo en un factor, así tiene un atributo de orden. Sin embargo el código que estás usando no funciona porque los niveles que defines para el factor no coinciden con los valores de Tipo. Es decir, con la función `factor` no puedes pasarles un orden numérico el `levels`, sino que debes pasarle un vector con las cadenas de caracteres ordenadas.

```
#No es necesario
#datos[order(datos$Valor),] -> datos

niveles <- c("Muy baja", "Baja", "Media", "Alta", "Desconocido")
datos$Tipo <- factor(datos$Tipo,  levels = niveles)
```

Algo parecido a lo que estabas buscando lo puedes hacer con la función `fct_inorder()` de la librería `forcats` (incluida en tidyverse).

Esa función crea un factor y ordena los niveles por orden de aparición en el factor o cadena de caracteres a partir de la cuál creamos el factor. Por defecto esto se hace alfabéticamente.

```
datos[order(datos$Valor),] -> datos

datos$Tipo <- fct_inorder(datos$Tipo)
```

Trabajando prefiero tomarme el tiempo para definir a mano los niveles en un vector, evitando depender del orden de un data.frame que puede perderse con las transformaciones. De todos modos cualquiera de las opciones son válidas.